Can I use the .gitmodules file instead of gitlinks to store submodule commits
The origin URL of a git submodule is saved in the file .gitmodules while the commit of the submodules is stored in a git tree as a special entry called "gitlink". This two-components system can have the following invalid configurations:

A gitlink without a .gitmodules entry: We have no submodule name then which is used by git config and also no url to clone a submodule from, so git submodule init will not work
A .gitmodules entry without gitlink could be salvageable by creating the gitlink from the path =  attribute in .gitmodules but still requires an additional commit to fix.

My coworkers want to use submodules from time to time as it allows to modularize research data, saving disk space and easing data protection while keeping reproducibility. However, they do not have doctoral degrees in informatics which means they have repeatedly ended up in one of the above two invalid states and do not know the git internals (blob, tree, gitlink) to understand the error messages and need to init the submodule or use obscure git commands to set the saved commit. Especially when solving merge conflicts involving different submodule versions gitlinks always have to be treated specially compared to other folders which makes us loose a lot of time calling obscure git commands.
It makes no sense to me why I need this convoluted fagile 2-component system. I want to use a simple additional line in each .gitmodules entry:
[submodule "submodule_name"]
url = https://example.org/submodule_name
path = folder/submodule
commit = 123456789abcdef...

This concept would go without having to explain people all the git internals when they do a merge. They would just see a merge conflict marker where one version has commit ID 1 and the other has commit ID 2 in a simple text editor.
How can I have git submodules without gitlinks, using a commit ID in .gitmodules. As a bonus, if you know how we ended up with the current system, I would be interested from an academic perspective ;-)
